# Regex for capital letters followed be a space followed by numbers 'ABC 123' or 'BLZ 420'

Tags: python, regex

So I have this script that identifies `ABC-123`

```
e = r'[A-Z]+-\d+'
```

shouldn't this identify `ABC 123`

```
e = r'[A-Z]+/s\d+'
```

Or am I missing something blindingly obvious. This is in Python as well.

Answer (score 5):

You have the wrong slash, you need a backslash:

```
e = r'[A-Z]+\s\d+'
```

`/s` will match `/` followed by a `s` literally, whereas `\s` is a Regex token that indicates a whitespace.